# Angularjs to return $http response to caller Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

How can I pass the response value to the parent object.  The invoker who make the http service call in angularjs?  What I have is a BaseModel where it will do the get like following.  The idea is basemodel object instance should have the reponse values.  BTW i am trying to avoid to use broadcast and on.

To invoke the object

> ```
>  model = new BaseModel();
>  model.get();
> ```

Definition:

> ```
> BaseModel.$service = ['$http', '$q',
>    function ($http, $q) {
>        return function () {
>            return new BaseModel($http, $q);
>        };
> ```
>
> }];

the actual BaseModel:

> ```
> function BaseModel($http, $q) {
>    var q = $q.defer();
>    this.http = $http;
>    this.response = null // this is to hold the response value
>    this.get = function () {
>        var request = this.http({
>            url: 'http://blahblah.com?a=1&b=2',
>            method: "GET",
>        });
>        request.success(function (response) {
>            q.resolve(response);
>        });
>
>        q.promise.then(
>            function(response){
>                console.log(response, ' got response');
>                //the idea is to have this.response = response
>                return response;
>            }
>        );
>        return q.promise
>    };
> ```

Comment: Consturctors should probably not make HTTP requests from a design perspective.

Comment: I don't think the constructor make http request.  In BaseModel there is a get function.  That get function will perform HTTP request

Comment: Not relate to the question, but why create an another promise? The `$http` already return a promise, you can use it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a self variable so you can refer to the BaseModel's instance variables:

```
function BaseModel($http, $q) {
  var self = this;
  self.response = null;
  /* ... rest of code ... */

    q.promise.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response, ' got response');
      self.response = response;
    });

  /* ... rest of code ... */
}
```

The issue isn't angularjs related ,it's related to how objects work in JavaScript and how you have to create a separate `self` reference because `this` refers to the inner-most function.